# USB switch faster on one PC than the other

Tags: usb, hub

I've recently bought a two usb switch from startech so I can use a usb hub between my work laptop an and my home pc.
I have a external USB 3 drive on the hub.
when I transfer files to my work laptop I get 100mb/sec. But to my home pc only 40mb/sec. I've checked in using usb 3 ports all round and I've swapped cables.
my desktop pc is about 8 years old where as my laptop is a year old. could it be a variation in usb 3 port quality?
I'm stumped otherwise.

It is [this startech switch](https://www.startech.com/uk/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Hubs/2-Port-2-to-1-USB-3-Peripheral-Sharing-Switch~USB221SS).
My desktop PC is a

- i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz,
- Gigabye GA-Z77X-D3H (6 usb 3.0 ports),
- 32gb Ram,
- 1tb ssd,
- 4tb hd,
- 2070 RTX card.

Answer (score 0):

From web [review section at NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/startech-usb221ss/p/N82E16817707314):

> Not suitable for power hungry devices.11/19/2016 10:31:21 PM Pros:
>   Lightweight. Works well with printers, keyboards, and mice.
>
> Cons: No option to supplement the power. Sometimes bus power is not
>   enough. I purchased to share an external HDD between my PC and my
>   router so I could have the contents of my HDD available on my network,
>   but quickly switch to a direct USB 3.0 PC connection for fast data
>   transfer. What i got was transfer rates of about 1/3 (40 MB/s) the
>   transfer speed of when directly connected (152 MB/s). My external HDD
>   requires ac power, so perhaps this would not be the case with a
>   portable HDD that requires only bus power.
>
> Overall Review: I ended up using the device to share a keyboard/mouse
>   combo between another PC and an android TV box. For this, it works
>   great.

Apparently your old PC has some problem with this switch (Rx detect, signal loss, or something) and downgrades the link to USB 2.0 mode. Eight years ago the USB 3 was in rudimentary state.

You can try to add a modern PCIe USB card (VIA or ASM or Renesas or else), the results will likely be better.

Comment: ok thanks. The switch connects to a hub which is powered.
The plot thickens.....i spoke to startech support and whilst swapping usb ports my pc froze, so i rebooted but i disconnected and reconnected the external hd. When it rebooted i suddenly had usb 3.0 performance ie 100mb/sec.
Startech suggested rebooting to double check, So i rebooted and then it was back to USB 2.0 speeds ie 40/mb sec. 
So i plugged the hub into the pc directly, and it was still slow.
I then plugged the external hd directly into my pc usb 3.0 port and its still running slow. So must be my desktop usb ports?

Comment: I checked they definitely are usb 3.0 as sometimes they run fine at that speed. Device manager shows no conflicts.

Comment: @paulr, this is not about device conflict or else. The switch introduces extra signal loss, and your old USB controller becomes flaky.